# Resolver $y''-2y'+5y=4e^x\cos(2x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Alguien que sepa resolver la ecuación diferencial homogenea:
$$y''-2y'+5y=4e^x\cos(2x)$$

$Y_p=?$
Llevo horas y aún no me da.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I changed the tag from "discrete mathematics" to "ordinary differential equations." What have you tried so far? Your question is about finding a particular solution - what have you learned about finding a particular solution?

Comment: Please translate your question to english or if OP does not know english then I would suggest someone else doing this

Comment: What if the OP doesn't know English? I think we should still help (provided that the OP would have shown their attempts in the original question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y''-2y'+5y=4e^x\cos(2x)$$
Substitute $y=ze^x$ you have:
$$z''+4z=4\cos (2x)$$
For the particular solution try:
$$z_p=Bx\sin (2x)$$
Then
$$y_p=e^xz_p$$